# Getting started with Rails on Heroku using a Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, foreman

Using a vanilla rails install using git (in fact following the heroku guide here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3)

However it mentions the creation of a Procfile

> web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV

Yet if you run this is needs using foreman start, you receive an error because you haven't defined the RACK_ENV

> 20:45:26 web.1     | started with pid 26364 20:45:27 web.1     |
>   /SomeLocalPath/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:33:in
>   `parse!': missing argument: -e (OptionParser::MissingArgument)

Where should this -e argument be stored for this all to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean that you are getting this error on your local development machine.

You can set the RACK_ENV when starting foreman like this, for example:

```
RACK_ENV=development foreman start
```

Or you could use a different procfile for development (e.g. "Procfile-dev") which has the value for the option -e inline, like this:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p 3000 -e development
```

and call it with:

```
  foreman start -f Procfile-dev
```

(On Heroku, it should just work, because when you run "heroku config -s" while you are in your app-folder, you should see "RACK_ENV=production", so the needed environment variable is set correctly here).

Comment: doing it this way results in the following error `method_missing': undefined method `development' for #<MyTestApp::Application:0x007fd28c5847b8> (NoMethodError)

Comment: on what OS are you? win/mac/linux? it works fine on my ubuntu machine using ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: spun up a new rails application using the above settings and it works. so my new error must be something else. i'll raise another question for it. thanks for your help